# F#: Is the "fun" keyword necessary?

Tags: f#, lambda

I was typing the "fun" keyword and then I remembered you don't have to in C#

Wouldn't this:

`List.map (x -> x + 1) [1..10]`

Be just as expressive as this?:

`List.map (fun x -> x + 1) [1..10]`

This makes me curious as to why the "fun" keyword is necessary at all. Can someone clarify why the "fun" keyword is syntactically required?

Comment: I don't know anything about F#, but I find the fact that it has a keyword named "fun".. funny

Comment: because coding in F# is fun! Its a friendly reminder while coding :)

Comment: If they took it out, there would be no fun in f#! 

Seriously though, that's curious as lambdas in C# don't need the keyword. It may be there just to simplify the parse. As languages evolve, these sorts of things tend to get reduced out/made optional.

Comment: Good point re evolution @Jim. It may be an aid to reduce the learning curve of F# and once it is/may be more widely used keywords which are implied may be removed.

Comment: it's necessary if you want it to compile :)

Comment: Isn't the fun keyword also a leftover from the ML family of languages? Haskell seems to get by okay with just using a backslash.

Comment: @yatima2975: I'm not really sure a backslash is so much less. It's a couple of characters shorter — otherwise they're identical. Both are tokens indicating a lambda.

Comment: A nice Haskellian backslash would be nice, instead of fun. Well at least it reminds me more of the lambda symbol

Comment: @yatima2975: Yes, SML has 'fun' too.

Comment: Strangely, SML uses `fun` in place of `let rec`. The equivalent to OCaml and F#'s `fun` is `fn`.

Comment: Beside, there is an issue about this on [GitHub](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/168)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The language is ambiguous without it.

```
let x y = y z -> y z
```

Does `x` call `y` on the function `z -> y z` or does it ignore its argument and return the function `y z -> y z`?

Comment: hmm good point, but surely you could add parenthesis to solve the ambiguity: "y (z -> y z)"? hmm... would that just end up making things more verbose?

Comment: But then you've just transformed `fun` into `()`. C# can get away with not having a special syntax for lambdas because it has a more elaborate syntax to begin with. In a language like F#, I don't see how you can get around using some kind of delimiter to say "OK, lambda coming up!"

Comment: I don't think this has to be ambiguous, most languages have tons of ambiguity, and there are precedence rules that are used to 'break' the ambiguity.  This could possibly be another such case.

Comment: @Brian: I'm trying to think of how such a rule would be expressed without making other parts of the language more confusing. It seems like the only simple choices are "every identifier before a `->` is an argument" (the "turn `fun` into `()`" option) or "lambdas only take one argument" (which I guess would bring us closer to lambda calculus). There's probably another option I haven't thought of, but I do think `fun` is a pretty simple solution here.

Answer (score 17):

Lots of decent speculative answers already... I'll add to the mix:

F# has a core language that's compatible with OCaml, and OCaml uses 'fun'.

Answer (score -1):

I know as part of currying, (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896170/coding-practice-for-f)) you can replace:

```
let countOneToTen = fun y List.map(fun x -> x + 1) y
countOneToTen = [1..10]
```

with

```
let countOneToTen y = List.map(fun x -> x + 1) y
countOneToTen = [1..10]
```

without the fun keyword.

Comment: That's not what the OP is talking about. They are instead asking why `fun x -> x + 1` can't just be `x -> x + 1`.

Comment: The question is asking whether "the 'fun' keyword is necessary at all," I was giving another example of where it can be used and omitted depending on developer preference.

Comment: I know (and I'm not the one who downvoted you, to be clear). Although I honestly don't know why anyone would prefer the version that doesn't take advantage of partial application. :)

Comment: I see where you are coming from @bcat.  This is a scenario where I would use the partial application of it as well, however I was talking more general.  I find (assuming the functions are named correctly), currying functions (apart from reducing no. param values) provides a clearer flow of code. (*Note: I am still learning F# too! :) )